# is it possible to get next_post_link

Tags: posts, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I have come across a problem whilst using the next_post_link() function.
It seems that this function automatically echo's, for position reasons I need this to just return the link. Is there any available function or workaround that I can use to achieve this result?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try to work with http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post;

example:

```
$next_post_link_url = get_permalink( get_adjacent_post(false,'',false)->ID ); 
$prev_post_link_url = get_permalink( get_adjacent_post(false,'',true)->ID );
```

Comment: Bear in mind this will only get the adjacent *URL* - you'll have to generate the HTML like `next_post_link` does yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the source, `next_post_link` is just a wrapper for `adjacent_post_link`.

Unfortunately, this function doesn't take any form of 'echo' parameter, so you'll either need to replicate the code in your own function & return the value, or catch it in an output buffer;

```
ob_start();
next_post_link();
$next_post_link = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes: just use `get_next_posts_link()`, using the same arguments.

The `next_posts_lin()` function simply echoes the returned value of `get_next_posts_link()`.

**EDIT**

Erm, nevermind. I mis-read the function name.

You could use `get_next_post()`, which returns a post object; then you could get the permalink from the returned ID object parameter:

```
$nextpost = `get_next_post( $args )`;
$nextpostid = $nextpost->ID;
$nextpostlink = get_permalink( $nextpostid );
```